# Finding covariance matrix for bootstrapped errors in OLS

Tags: statistics, least-squares, law-of-large-numbers, bootstrap-sampling

Let's say we have matrix $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta^*$ vector, which $\beta^* = \arg\min_\phi\sum_i (y_i - x_i\phi)$, i.e. we have classic regression problem and $\beta^*$ is $OLS(y, x)$ solution.
Final model represented as $y = x\beta^* + \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon -$vector of residuals with unknown parameters and distribution, parameters we want to estimate.

Using bootstrap, we can construct vector $\varepsilon^b$ from vector $\varepsilon$, having then vector $y^b$ as $y^b = x\beta^* + \varepsilon^b$. Then we estimate $\beta^b = OLS(y^b, x)$. Doing this an infinite number of times, we get accurate bootstrapped distribution of random vector $\varepsilon^b$.

Now, having the knowledge that we **included** intercept term (i.e. column of ones in **x** matrix, turning it into matrix $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (k+1)}$), we need to prove that $\mathbb{E}\beta^b = \beta^*$ and covariance matrix $cov(\beta^b) = \frac{\sum_i (y_i - x_i\beta^*)^2}{n}(x^Tx)^{-1}$.

**My approach:** knowing that we have column ones and fact that residual vector $\varepsilon$ is orthogonal to each column of $x$, get $\varepsilon \cdot 1 = 0 \Rightarrow \bar{\varepsilon} = 0$. Using infinity and LLN we get $\mathbb{E}\varepsilon = 0$. From normal equation $\beta^b = (x^Tx)^{-1}x^Ty^b = \beta^* + (x^Tx)^{-1}x^T\varepsilon^b$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}\beta^b = \beta^* + (x^Tx)^{-1}x^T\mathbb{E}\varepsilon^b = \beta^*$. Though I have troubles with second fact.

**Question:** how we can prove second? How to show that $\varepsilon^b$ has variance $\frac{\sum_i (y_i - x_i\beta^*)^2}{n}$?

Comment: It looks like $\frac{\sum_i (y_i - x_i\beta^*)}{n}$ can be negative. Also, $\beta^* = \arg\min_\phi\sum_i (y_i - x_i\phi)^2$.

Comment: @d.k.o. my bad, updated and added squares

Comment: OK. What is the source of randomness in the bootstrap procedure?

Comment: @d.k.o. what do you mean? We use simple bootstrap with replacement

Comment: You didn't mention that...

Comment: @d.k.o. it is not mentioned in the task either. But assume that bootstrap here done by the next procedure: we take our objects ($\varepsilon_i$) and put it in a bag. Than $n$ (size of $\varepsilon$ vector) times we draw an object and than put it back in the bag. Repeat this an infinite amount of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
$$
\beta^b=\beta^*+(x^{\top}x)^{-1}x^{\top}\varepsilon^b.
$$
Now, for $i=1,\ldots,n$,
$$
\mathsf{E}[\varepsilon_i^b\mid y, x]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \varepsilon_j^*=0,
$$
$\operatorname{Cov}(\varepsilon_i^b,\varepsilon_j^b\mid y, x)=0$ for $i\ne j$, and
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon_i^b\mid y, x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (\varepsilon_j^{*})^2.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathsf{E}[\beta^b\mid y, x]=\beta^*,
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\beta^b\mid y, x)=(x^{\top}x)^{-1}x^{\top}\operatorname{Var}(\varepsilon^b\mid y, x)x(x^{\top}x)^{-1}=(x^{\top}x)^{-1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (\varepsilon_j^{*})^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why $Cov(\varepsilon_i^b, \varepsilon_j^b|y, x) = 0$ for $i \ne j$? And why $Var(\varepsilon_i^b|y, x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n (\varepsilon_j^*)^2$?

Comment: @taciturno $\varepsilon_i^b$ and $\varepsilon_j^b$ are indepndent (conditionally on $(y,x)$). For the variance, note that $\varepsilon_i^b$ equals $\varepsilon_j^*$ with probability $1/n$, and the mean of $\varepsilon_1^*,\ldots, \varepsilon_n^*$ is zero.

Comment: BTW, I used $\varepsilon^*$ for the vector of sample residuals (instead of $\varepsilon$).